# Use tun0 (TUN interface) with Scrapy

Tags: python, networking, scrapy, tun

I want to use use different interface to make requests from Scrapy (`tun0`, instead of `eth0)`. Can somebody explain, how to do it with Scrapy? In curl I'm just specified `--interface tun0`. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved. Use [bindaddress meta key](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#bindaddress) to specify outgoing IP address (just use IP address of your interface).